# Find $|BD|$ in the following quadrilateral...

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

This is a preparation question for our national college entry exams;

[image]

Translating the paragraph;

$AB \perp BC$, $ACD$ is an equilateral triangle, $|AB|=2$, $|BC|=\sqrt{3}$,$|BD|=x$,,, Find $x$.

**My Attempts**

I have named $m(\widehat{CAB})=\alpha$, $\cos\alpha=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt7}$ and we can easily see that $|AD|=\sqrt{7}$ (1)

Then I've tried to calculate $x$ from cosines theorem in triangle $BAD$ (2)

I've calculated $\cos(60^\circ+\alpha)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{7}}$ (3)

Then I've applied the theorem: $4+7-2\cos(60^\circ+\alpha)=x^2$ (4)

What baffled me here a little is that we don't know whether $60+\alpha >90$ or not (5)

Let's pretend it isn^'t I said and then jumped to a conclusion like $x=\sqrt{11+\sqrt{3}}$ then I've tried to open it up a little more but I failed (9)

So the question is;

**If** my calculations are correct then this result isn't in the answers, is the question flawed? ( A little daring perhaps) If they are not how should I have done it, how could I know whether $60+\alpha>90$ or not? And the most important question, is there an easier way? (Perhaps one that skips all cosines and etc.) (I would be totally fine with a solution from area or sine theorem)

Thank you:))

Answer (score 1):

by the Theorem of cosines we get
$$BD^2=3+CD^2-6\cdot CD\cos(60^{\circ}+\alpha)$$(I)
further $$CD=AC=\sqrt{7}$$ (II)
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$ (III)
Can you solve your Problem now?

Comment: Thank you, but no I can't because I still don't know whether $\cos(60^\circ+\alpha)$ is greater than $90^\circ$ or not. And I unfortunately couldn't understand why you used $\tan(\alpha)$

Comment: from this equation you can compute $$\alpha$$

Comment: I am not so good at trigonometry unfortunately, can you explain it a little further?

Comment: what want you do know exactly?

Comment: I want to know whether the options below the question are correct or not, because as far as I have calculated the options do not respect trig solutions.

Comment: And also is the right way to see if $60+\alpha$ is greater or smaller than $90$ do we need to know what $\alpha$ is?

Comment: in my solution you Need to know what $\alpha$ is, take a calculator and compute $\alpha$

Comment: you are welcome! nice that i could help you

Answer (score 1):

You're probably making a calculation mistake. I've got x = 4 here. Your method is correct.

About the fact that whether cos(60 + alpha) is more than 0 or not, just expand it using the sum formula and plug in the values of sin alpha and cos alpha then you'll be able to figure out whether it is gonna be more than 0 or not.

Comment: Calculation mistakes always get me, thank you:)

Comment: Everybody does mate. I can assure that I occasionally make more calculation mistakes than you lol.